# After upgrade to 2.4.3 error 404 in main content

Tags: magento2

After upgrade from 2.3.7 to 2.4.3 the page is working, only the main content area is displaying 404 error op al pages. I think it has something to do with the pub folder but can't figure out what.

The .htaccess is pointing to the index in a pub, so it bootstraps from there.

Logo and menu/footer are visible, but main content displays 404

[http://185.56.144.149/~jilco01/tricot-kinderstoffen.html](http://185.56.144.149/%7Ejilco01/tricot-kinderstoffen.html)

Comment: is it possible that you have a folder in your installation's hostname?

Comment: No there is no folder

Comment: do you have 'document_root_is_pub' set on true in your env.php file?

Comment: No, is that nesscessery?

Comment: yes, let me provide more details in an official answer then

Comment: I did now and no diffence, do i need to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, please make sure that all steps detailed in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html are performed. Specially the 'document_root_is_pub' is true part ;)

Good luck!